# Auto Provisioning the IOS application in Installrapp.com

Tags: java, ios, jsoup, jaunt-api, installr

Basically, I need to update below screen shot details for every application generated or every build occurs in Installr app. I thoroughly checked API there is no method to help the above scenario.
I need to auto Provisioning the IOS application for each Build.
Now I am trying to accomplish that above task using Java, Jsoup web Scraping Technic . Please Let us know if the task is not possible to using above techs stack also suggest me any other JS to full fill the requirement.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I can see two options for you:

#### Option 1: Stay with your current techs stack...

1. Fire up the network tab in the developer toolbar of your favorite browser.
2. Play the scenario manually in your browser and carefully study the **HTTP exchanges** between your browser and the server.
3. Once you have understand the exchanges made, reproduce them with Jsoup in your Java code.

#### Option 2: Change your techs stack

I suggest you to try one the tools below:

- [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org)
- [ui4j](https://github.com/ui4j/ui4j)

Both handle Javascript and will facilitate the automation of your scenario.
They will automatically determine the appropriate exchanges to do.